# Proving an exponent property

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know this might be an easy task but I cannot seem to get anywhere with this proof:

I am given this:
$\exp(x)=$ $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$.

I have to prove that:
$\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$.

Comment: I presume that the point of the exercise is NOT to use that property of the exponential but rather to prove it from this definition.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder You can flag this as a dupe, so that it will enter into the Close Queue, and 3k users will mark them as a dupe

Comment: @GNUSupporter I did, and have edited the comment text thereafter. Sorry for the confusion.